# AWS EC2 ipaddress

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, elastic-ip

I managed to login to ubuntu and do some installation and ftp some image files(just to test if the network works). How can I view it using Public IP or Elastic IP from browser? I don't want to transfer the DNS yet because I am testing out the Node.js for now.

Comment: You want to serve the files with Node.js, or you want to view them in a static way (`http://dns-to-my-server/some_image.jpg`)?

Comment: @Uri Agassi Yes I want to view them in a static way like you say, to complete the whole learning circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launching an ubuntu instance on EC2 does not automatically make it a server. You need to actually run a web-server in order to see files from that computer on your browser.

For static files, you can use simple web server like [python's SimpleHTTPServer](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/tech-tip-really-simple-http-server-python) or [webfsd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man1/webfsd.1.html).

If you are planning to work with node.js, you might prefer writing a small [Hello World](http://howtonode.org/hello-node) in node.js instead:

```js
// Load the http module to create an http server.
var http = require('http');

// Configure our HTTP server to respond with Hello World to all requests.
var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.end("Hello World\n");
});

// Listen on port 8000, IP defaults to 127.0.0.1
server.listen(8000);

// Put a friendly message on the terminal
console.log("Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/");
```

Comment: This works for me thanks, but I finally decided to start from scratch with [this tutorial](http://techprd.com/setup-node-js-web-server-on-amazon-ec2/), just to see if I miss out anything important.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this is to do with the NodeJS server definition

The default server.listen given in the examples

> server.listen(1337, "127.0.0.1");

NodeJS will only listen to connections from 127.0.0.1.

To get it to respond to all requests, try the following setupthe host part is optional)

> server.listen(1337);

Comment: Sorry I am rather new to the server side. Do you mind give me some example code?

Comment: `var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8080, "0.0.0.0");
console.log('Server running at http://0.0.0.0:8080/');`


Replace 8080 with your own code.  The important part is the .listen(port,IP);  if you don't specify this it will only listen to localhost (127.0.0.1)

Comment: Sorry for the newbie question, but where do I do this code you provide? In node nano?

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow the port where you are running node.js on the security group that your EC2 instance is using.  Then you can access your site at `http://<public ip of your server>:<port where node.js is running on>`

[image: Node.js port]

Comment: Yes I already done that. I can connect with CLI and SFTP. But I am not sure how to make it work for browser. Anything else that I can check?

Answer (score 0):

1. An EC2 instance isn't a web server by default.

   sudo apt-get install httpd

should do the trick.
You will then need to start the server by:

```
sudo service httpd start
```

Then I would test the working by creating index.html at the following location using the command.

```
sudo vim /var/www/html index.html
```

2. Default Security Group settings do not allow inbound traffic. If you go to the AWS EC2 console using:
   [AWS EC2 Instance Console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/v2/home?region=us-west-1#Instances:sort=instanceId)
   and EDIT the security group. Allow HTTP for all IP.
3. Now if you go to {https:// YOUR-PUBLIC-IP-ADDRESS/}, it should display the html contents of index.html.
   Images can be added on similar notes.